# direct Authenthication to LDAP Active Directory using Javascript and PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ldap, cordova

I´m currently building a mobile webclient application with PhoneGap / Cordova using web technologies HTML5, CSS3, Javascript and the Frameworks JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap / Cordova. The mobile webclient needs to authenticate to a LDAP Active Directory in order to use the application (just username and password are needed).  If possible, there shouldn´t be any web/application server in between for the authentication (is that possible anyway?).

This authentication should be done entirely via web technologies and be as operating-system-independent as possible (so no Android Java or iOS objective-C code for using sockets)

I heard about using web sockets for the authentication, but it seems that there is no web socket support for PhoneGap / Cordova  nor web-based LDAP authentication(?)

So could you tell me if its basically possible to authenticate to a AD via LDAP from a mobile client using PhoneGap / Cordova, JQuery mobile and web technologies Javascript, HTML5, CSS3 without using operating system dependent technologies (Android, iOS)?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Yadrick, have you got any solution for this?